# How to combine multiple rows of strings into one using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, text, dataframe, concatenation

I have a DataFrame with multiple rows. Is there any way in which they can be combined to form one string?

For example:

```
     words
0    I, will, hereby
1    am, gonna
2    going, far
3    to
4    do
5    this
```

Expected output:

```
I, will, hereby, am, gonna, going, far, to, do, this
```

Comment: What is the type of elements? I am guessing `0`, `1` , etc is index right?

Comment: indexes are like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `str.cat` to join the strings in each row. For a Series or column `s`, write:

```
>>> s.str.cat(sep=', ')
'I, will, hereby, am, gonna, going, far, to, do, this'
```

Comment: i tried the above mentioned code. It give me an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'.       Is this because there are blank rows in the dataframe as well?    If so, how can i rectify it?

Comment: The `.str` accessor only works on a Series or a single column of a DataFrame (not an entire DataFrame). If you want to apply this method to multiple columns of a DataFrame, you'll need to use it on each column individually in turn.

Comment: thanks, could you also help me out with the syntax for the above?       If i want to concatenate the rows of column 'words' of dataframe df, how should i write it?    Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure - to apply the method to the 'words' column, you could write `df['words'].str.cat(sep=', ')` (where `df` is the name of your DataFrame).

Comment: sorry, but it gives me this error: 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found'           I believe this is because each row is a list in itself. Any resort for this?

Comment: If you have lists, you need to create strings first. Change the lists in the column to strings with `df['words'].str.join(', ')` and then use the above method.

Comment: Thankyou soo much... It finally worked!! You have been really helpful and patient, thanks!!!!!

Comment: I'm surprised `str.cat` is slower to `join()` method. Do check the solution and timings below.

Answer (score 28):

How about traditional python's `join`? And, it's faster.

```
In [209]: ', '.join(df.words)
Out[209]: 'I, will, hereby, am, gonna, going, far, to, do, this'
```

Timings in Dec, 2016 on pandas 0.18.1

```
In [214]: df.shape
Out[214]: (6, 1)

In [215]: %timeit df.words.str.cat(sep=', ')
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.2 µs per loop

In [216]: %timeit ', '.join(df.words)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14 µs per loop

In [217]: df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

In [218]: df.shape
Out[218]: (60000, 1)

In [219]: %timeit df.words.str.cat(sep=', ')
100 loops, best of 3: 5.2 ms per loop

In [220]: %timeit ', '.join(df.words)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: Interesting timings, I get a similar result on 0.19.2. However, I think the trade-off here is that `str.cat` will seamlessly handle missing values like `NaN` and `None` (you can even supply the `na_rep` argument to choose how to represent these missing values). Python's `join` fails here. You can get around this by filtering-out/filling-in missing values and *then* joining, but this slows it right back down. Filling missing values like this also fails if the column holds categorical values; `str.cat` just works.

Comment: How does this works, If i do not want to have the seperators of a coma? What if my outcome should be:  `I will hereby am gonna going far to do this`

Comment: @PV8 you can try " ".join(...) instead of ", ".join(...)

Answer (score 18):

If you have a `DataFrame` rather than a `Series` and you want to concatenate values (I think text values only) from different rows based on another column as a 'group by' key, then you can use the `.agg` method from the class `DataFrameGroupBy`. Here is a [link to the API manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).

Sample code tested with Pandas v0.18.1:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 2,
    'name': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2'],
    'num': range(1, 6)
})

df.groupby('category').agg({
    'name': lambda x: ', '.join(x),
    'num': lambda x: x.max()
})
```

Comment: minor comment: need to assign to a new dataframe i.e.df2 = df.groupby(...)

Comment: groupby with agg and lambda is quite slow on larger dataframes... is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: dude thx for this, it rlly helps me to solve another groupby problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone want to know how to combine multiple rows of strings in `dataframe`,
I provide a method that can concatenate strings within a 'window-like' range of near rows as follows:

```py
# add columns based on 'windows-like' rows
df['windows_key_list'] = pd.Series(df['key'].str.cat([df.groupby(['bycol']).shift(-i)['key'] for i in range(1, windows_size)], sep = ' ')
```

Note: 
This can't be reached by `groupby`,  because we don't mean the same id of rows, just near rows.